# Is my use of curl_multi() still serial? If so, how can I parallelize?

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I got a hint from someone today that my `curl_multi()` code is actually working in serial, when my hope was to parallelize the cURL requests.

**Is my code still serial?** If so, how I can parallelize?

Here's the relevant code:

```
  /**
   * Returns the cURL responses given multiple target URLs
   * @param array $targetUrls Array of target URLs for cURL
   *
   * @return array cURL Responses
   */
  private function getCurlMultiResponses($targetUrls)
  {
    // Cache the count
    $count = count($targetUrls);

    // Create the multiple cURL handles
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
      $ch[$i] = curl_init($targetUrls[$i]);
      curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
      curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
      curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    }

    // Initialize the multiple cURL handle
    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    // Add the handles to the curl_multi handle
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
      curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
    }

    $running = null;
    // Execute the handles
    do {
      curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while ($running > 0);

    $responses = array();

    // Remove the handles and return the response
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
      curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);

      $responses[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$i]);
    }

    // Close the multiple cURL handle
    curl_multi_close($mh);

    return $responses;
  }
```

Comment: Also, please give the [http extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.http.php) a try. It has a request pool for parallel processing. And unlike cURL it's not an intermediate API. (curl is not intended as HTTP client solely, just happens to support it among SSH, FTP, IMAP, etc.)

Comment: @mario: I didn't realize the http extension could handle parallel processing. I'll have to take a look at some point (lower priority for me atm), but it's worth keeping in mind! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) certainly suggests it's a parallel operation:

> Allows the processing of multiple cURL handles in parallel.

There's a good tutorial [here](http://www.codediesel.com/php/parallel-curl-execution/).

Comment: Indeed. That's what I thought. My guess is that the confusion was over the response of `curl_multi_exec()`, which is just so PHP know its status. So it checks that in serial, but the cURL streams themselves are parallel.